# zull, eureka server, eureka service and docker

Tags: docker, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have a question about docker and microservices. So, I've created ZuulService, EurekaServer + EurekaService and it's working without docker.
But I'm trying to study docker and I created my dockerfile, created jar with Maven and created and ran docker-compose.yml. (thanks, Maven)

Eureka works, but Zuul says that connection is refused:

```
2020-08-01 14:39:12.463  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2020-08-01 14:39:12.695 ERROR 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

application.yml

```
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    user:
      path: /cat/**
      serviceId: CAT

    country:
      path: /country/**
      serviceId: COUNTRY

    about:
      path: /about/**
      servcieId: ABOUT


ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 10000
  ReadTimeout: 30000

hystrix:
  threadpool:
    default:
      coreSize: 1000
      maximumSize: 10000
      queueSizeRejectionThreshold: -1
      maxQueueSize: -1
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 41000
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=ZuulService
server.port=8080

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

Comment: well, 3 services, but whatever, if i can get work just one, i can do it with others

Answer (score 0):

So, changed in zuul properties to

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://eureka-service:8761/eureka
```

and ran docker-compose.yml, waited until eureka starts, then restarted zuul & other services. Eureka registered them.